# Custom Objects Record Type Deactivations

Tags: visualforce, record-type

What happens when a custom objects record type is made inactive without transferring the record to another recordtype.

Comment: Record type is required field. If you inactivate one, you have to pick replacement RT

Answer (score 1):

Nothing occurs to the existing data. Deactivating a record type means it can no longer be selected for new records, and existing records can no longer be changed to that record type. Existing records of that record type can still be edited without changing the record type. Upon deletion of a record type, however, all records with the affected record type must be changed to a new record type.